# Removing Zero from R table based on main variable

Tags: r

I have this data set in R

```
dd=data.frame(
main=c("G","G","G","R","R","R","Y","Y","Y"),test=c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1),
a = c(1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0), b= c(0,3,0,0,6,0,0,4,0), c=c(0,0,5,0,0,8,0,0,9))
```

I want to look like this

```
     main test a   b   c  
[1,] G 1 1 3 5
[2,] R 1 2 6 8
[3,] Y 1 3 4 9
```

I have some code but it is not working properly.

You help is much appropriated

Comment: What's the rule for the "test" column? For the others, you can just use `aggregate`.

Comment: I really appreciate if you can help without criticize me and vote up for me instead down to support me learn.

Comment: To learn here, you are responsible for asking an answerable question. This is only answerable with some expertise and guesswork as to what you're after (as Pierre provided below), since you chose to offer no explanation whatsoever in the question itself. If I were you, I wouldn't fight over the downvotes; just try to formulate your question better next time.

Comment: I have search if this question was asked before and I didn't find anything and I am new R user maybe if you can be more reasonable and provide the link it wouldn't hurt rather than downvote my question. it is only an indicator and I need it in my dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can just use the function `max` inside `aggregate` as in the `dplyr` solution by @Pierre Lafortune.

```
aggregate(. ~ main , data = dd, max)
```

Output:

```
  main test a b c
1    G    1 1 3 5
2    R    1 2 6 8
3    Y    1 3 4 9
```

`sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT main, max(test) test, max(a) a, max(b) b, max(c) c 
      FROM dd 
      GROUP BY main")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
aggregate(.~main, aggregate(.~main+test, dd, sum), sum)
#  main test a b c
#1    G    1 1 3 5
#2    R    1 2 6 8
#3    Y    1 3 4 9
```

First we aggregate by "main" and "test". With that aggregate, we then group by "main" only. The nested process allows us to first add the "a, b, c" columns, then we can do a full collapse after.

For a `data.table` solution from @AnandaMahto,

```
as.data.table(dd)[, test := max(test), by = "main"][, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(main, test)]
#   main test a b c
#1:    G    1 1 3 5
#2:    R    1 2 6 8
#3:    Y    1 3 4 9
```

This `dplyr` solution also:

```
dd %>% group_by(main) %>% summarise_each(funs(max))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#
#  main test a b c
#1    G    1 1 3 5
#2    R    1 2 6 8
#3    Y    1 3 4 9
```

It really does depend on your end product. I'm having trouble seeing how adding the test id along with the rest of the columns can help, but maybe there's a method to your madness :)

Comment: @AnandaMahto Or `data.table(dd)[,lapply(.SD,sum), by=.(main,test=1+0*test)]` or `setDT(dcast(melt(dd,id.vars=c("main")),main~variable,sum))[, test := test/2][]`, though those are a bit silly :)